# How to scale the Nivo Slider down to mobile size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The responsive HTML5 site scales perfectly using media queries, but the slider does not scale or respond properly at all on any handheld device(s). The Dev7studios support forums are dreadfully bad, so forgive me for asking here. Anyone know how to scale the Nivo slider responsively?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this also

Comment: Well, after some searching, I found an excellent alternative to Nivo: http://flex.madebymufffin.com/

Comment: For future seeker, now nivo-slider is responsive http://nivo.dev7studios.com/2012/05/30/the-nivo-slider-is-responsive/

Comment: Although you did describe your problem, it is greatly appreciated to be able to see some code. Consider adding some code so that your question will have a much higher value

Answer (score 1):

In November 2011, a Nivo Slider support representative said:

> Unfortunately at the moment the slider is not responsive however this
>   is a feature we are working on for the next version... I'm afraid I
>   have no release date, but we are working on it.

[Source](http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/nivo-slider-wordpress-plugin/117-can-we-make-the-slider-responsive)

[EDIT] Dev7studios now says the latest version of Nivo Slider is "[completely responsive](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider/)."